# want to print full Name of the day

Tags: php, date

I want to print name of the day giving numbers from 1 to 7.

Ex:

```
<?php
 echo date("1");
?>
```

and want to get output as `Monday`. But it prints `1`.

Can any one help me?

Comment: That would help: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 28):

```
echo date ('l');
```

amazing what you find in the manual, its l not 1

> l (lowercase 'L')     A full textual representation of the day of the
>   week  Sunday through Saturday

**update**

sneakiness to not have to create your own array of day names

```
$day='1'; 
echo date("l", mktime(0,0,0,8,$day,2011));// it will work for day 1-7
```

Answer (score 19):

Use like:

```
$mydate = '2016-01-01';
echo date('l, F jS, Y', strtotime($mydate));
# Friday, January 1st, 2016
```

note the letter ***l*** (lower case of *L*)

Comment: What is `jS` refer to in date format?

Answer (score 6):

you cannot do that with `date()`

`date()` = Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given.

You can set an array with your values:

```
$dates = array("", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
echo $dates[1]; // will output Monday
```

if you want the current day name

```
echo date ('l'); // (lowercase 'L')
```

In other words read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
$mydate = '2016-09-25';
date('l', strtotime($mydate));
```

It is "l" l for lock :P

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to provide more explanation as to why this is a better solution than the five others that have been posted over the past five years. Currently, your answer is fairly vague.

Answer (score 1):

```
function dt($val) { 
    $arrWeek = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    return $arrWeek[$val];
}
```

Comment: why do it this way? when there's a built in function to do this already

Comment: @Dagon, Is there? I've never heard of an inbuilt function to turn `1` into `Monday`. Which were you thinking of?

Comment: i admit to reading and replying to fast, but you could do: $day='1';
echo date("l", mktime(0,0,0,8,$day,2011));// tis will work for day 1-7

Answer (score 1):

if some one using Carbon class which is inherited from the PHP [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) ,

```
Carbon::parse('yourdate')->formatLocalized('%A');
```

[Carbon API localization](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
echo date('l');
```

Also if you want to localize it:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");//you need to change C with your locale.
echo strftime("%A");
```

will solve your problem.