# PHP or MySQL Date Format for Day of Week

Tags: php, mysql, dayofweek

I have a column that stores a 1-digit value for Day of Week:

```
0 = Sunday
1 = Monday
...
6 = Saturday
```

I tried PHP `date('l', $row['dow'])` and MySQL `DATE_FORMAT(dow, '%w')` but neither return the Day of Week word.

Is it possible in PHP or MySQL to do this or do I just need to create an array() var?

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. Just trying to learn something, that's all. Someday I'll be at your level and can assist someone with these types of sincere questions.

Comment: You mean the opposite of [day of the week to day number (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2)? Just asking, I'd say it's likely this has been asked before, so instead of asking it again, this needs some research on the site first.

Comment: Related: [want to print full Name of the day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7063336/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a full date/timestamp for any of the date formatting functions to work. Just a "1" or "2" doesn't mean anything to these functions (or at least not what you want it to mean). If you are storing a full timestamp, there's no real need to store the day of the week again separately. Otherwise, you'll need to translate those otherwise meaningless numbers to a word yourself.

Comment: So the answer is you cannot do this in PHP using date() or MySQL using DATE_FORMAT() -- based on my question. You must setup your own array. Thanks for the answer @deceze !

Answer (score 2):

```
$dow = date('l', strtotime("Sunday +{$row['dow']} days"));
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LzZDHf

Comment: couldn't get this to work. Using @deceze's answer and setting up an array().

Comment: What were you trying? An array won't have locale support, but chances are you won't need it. Perhaps I/we can help.

Answer (score 1):

on `date( 'l' )`:

`l (lowercase 'L') - A full textual representation of the day of the week - Sunday through Saturday`

you should use date( 'w' ):

`w - Numeric representation of the day of the week - 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)`

**Edit**: ah, so you want the text representation from (only) the numer.
Then a simple *map* would be enough:

```
$dayNames = array( 'Sunday', 'Monday', ..., 'Saturday' );
$day = $dayNames[$row['dow']];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/bg/function.date.php

here are all codes for php date format

From your database select your how date and with php use
date('l', strtotime($date))

Comment: Thanks @Svetlio -- but I have them already (keep them printed and pinned on my b-board next to my desk. My question is: can I take a single value of, say "2" and get PHP or MySQL to return "Tuesday" without creating an array()? I can create the array, no problem. Just preferring to do it a little simpler if possible...that's all.

Comment: I tried that earlier @Svetlio -- each value returns "Wednesday". My suspicion is is it defaulting to the UNIX start date of 1/1/1970.

Comment: do you have dates before 1970 ?

Comment: No @Svetlio - -I have no dates. I simply have a column `day tinyint(1) UNSIGNED`. It contains a "0", or a "1", or a "2", or a "3", or a "4", or a "5", or a "6". That's it.

Comment: Then just create 1 php array eg.. 
$dates = array(0=>"Sunday", 1=>"Monday"....); 
and call it $dates[$row["dow"]] ;

When you dont have Timeformat you cant use time functions ..