# How to get number to week day name?

Tags: php

How to get week number to week day name??

This is what i see while searching for my solution, this is the example from where the month name retrieve from the month number.

```
$monthNum  = 3;
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
```

I want to get week day name from week number. How can i did this?? I try with `w` instead of `m`, also check this [datetime.createfromformat.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), please help me.

My desire is:

```
$day = 6;
$dayName = (....); // Saturday
```

> Note: 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

Comment: Try with creating array of days..

Comment: See here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063336/want-to-print-full-name-of-the-day

Comment: With out array is it not possible??

Answer (score 0):

Because [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) does not have format for **A number representation of a day**, it only has format for **A textual representation of a day**, so you must create an array contains the name of days to fetch number into name like this:

```
$dates = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
$day = 6;
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!D', $dates[$day]);
$dayName = $dateObj->format('l'); // Saturday
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check.